# Another "The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data." issue with WCF and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have no trouble retrieving a large amount of data, but sending it back to the service displays this error. I've tried adding the  element to both the web.config and servicereferences.clientconfig and it's not recognized in either. At one point I got a message about adding readerQuotas to bindingElementExtensions, but I can't find anything useful on how to do this. I found posts saying I had to modify the devenv.exe.config and such, but doing that hosed VS.

### Edit

Here's the binding section of the web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="QaRiM.Web.Service1.customBinding0">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="QaRiM.Web.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="QaRiM.Web.Service1.customBinding0"
      contract="QaRiM.Web.Service1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

and the servicereferences.clientconfig:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_Service1">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:36533/Service1.svc" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_Service1" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
                name="CustomBinding_Service1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Both were generated by VS.

Comment: Can you post the binding elements of your client and service config files? Also the endpoint for the service as well, since it should reference the binding.

Answer (score 9):

You are simply missing the configuration for the [maximum string content length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.maxstringcontentlength.aspx).

Add this to your binding attributes (client and server)

```
<readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
```

Sorry, I didn't realize that this child element is located under the encoding being used when using a custom binding, it appears to be`binaryMessageEncoding` in your example.  If not, try the other encodings with the setting.

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="QaRiM.Web.Service1.customBinding0">                  
            <binaryMessageEncoding>
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binaryMessageEncoding>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: That's the problem, it's not a valid binding attribute.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It's not valid in the services config and with it in the web.config every call to the services crashes the app.

Comment: Did you turn on tracing to see why it's crashing? This is the correct setting, but you may need to figure out which encoding to apply it to.

Comment: Look into WCF tracing for more detailed error messages. If it's failing, it will show it. You shouldn't have to resort to fiddler to see the exception.

Comment: WCF tracing doesn't seem to give me any more detail than Fiddler. There's still the issue with sending XML data that's more than 8K to the service.

Answer (score 2):

if The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.” is ignoring your web.config settings EVEN after you set
     
you can also solve the problem in your code by creating an instance of XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas and setting the MaxStringContentLength to 2147483647

then just use the instance of XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas seen here as mycreatedreaderquota

```
 XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas mycreatedreaderquota = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        mycreatedreaderquota.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;

        XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, mycreatedreaderquota);
```

Answer (score 1):

*edit*: This saved an incomplete draft, sorry

1. Synchronizing the service/client definitions is what you've done but it's definitely imperative that they match.
2. Are you sure you need custom binding? Have you tried using ws(Dual)HttpBinding as a base?
3. This post may be of interest: [silverlight 3 wcf service configuration -- getting maxreceivedmessagesize error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164065/silverlight-3-wcf-service-configuration-getting-maxreceivedmessagesize-error), specifically the *httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"* setting.
4. You may need to set *maxBufferPoolSize* and *maxItemsInObjectGraph*. The config in the linked SO post pretty much maxed everything out.
5. I don't know if you use the ChannelFactory client proxy method or the service reference method but you may wish to go the former route. In debug sessions I was finding certain values from the config weren't being applied as I had thought but my short term memory on the subject is rather lost now.
6. Related to #5 somewhat, you can run into WCF Test Client issues where the test client is using default bindings that you're not prepared for.
7. Another post that may be of interest: http://www.haveyougotwoods.com/archive/2008/04/14/wcf-message-streaming.aspx

Streaming is likely your best bet on the client side to keep from the blocking nature of buffered transferMode. I don't know the specifics of how big the data will be consistently but your service will behave a little nicer on the client end if you went that route. A good primer on configuring just the client side for streaming can be found here: http://systemmetaphor.blogspot.com/2009/05/using-wcf-to-transfer-large-data-files.html.

Hopefully some combination of the above helps

Comment: Using WCF tracing, nothing useful is displayed. Fiddler was the only reason I figured out the max string content length issue was the problem. I'm just guessing, but the thing about bindingElementExtensions seems relevant, I just can't find any info on how to add it correctly.

Comment: The bits that stood out in the documents I were finding on Google were  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647 /> and maxItemsInObjectGraph. The former because ASP.NET by default has a cap on request sizes and the latter was just really impressed as "the only thing I changed that seemed to do anything" kind of behavior.

Comment: It does seem like you are in the right direction though but you should be able to trace why the app is failing in ASP.NET. I've only used WCF in the self hosting route and I want to say that gave me a little more freedom to determine weird errors such as this without something like ASP.NET getting in the way (not that it does at all in most instances)

Comment: I know why the app is failing, it's why I can't fix it using the solutions I've found that's the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `maxStringContentLength` within the config for the service?  In my situation, setting it on the service allowed for the Silverlight client to use the desired value for `maxStringContentLength`.

One note is that if you are allowing longer strings, but don't adjust the `maxReceivedMessageSize`, than this can cause issues as well.  The `maxReceivedMessageSize` does need to be controlled on both the service and the client, as one will not inherit the values from another.